# How to find the lower and upper bound of m for an m-ary tree?

Tags: data-structures

A full m-ary tree T has 81 leaves and height 4,how to find the upper and lower bounds for m.

I am not getting this as according to me m>=3 ,so then how to find the lower bound for this.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit further what you questions is, please?

Answer (score 0):

The *lower* bound is indeed 3: since the number of nodes is multiplied by at most `m` at each depth, one needs an arity at least 3 to get 81 leaves at depth 4.

Now, let's talk about the *upper* bound.

Consider this tree:

```
    o
   /|\
  o o o
 /|\
o o o
```

If by *full* you mean that each node of depth < 4 has `m` children, then the example is not full. In this case, `m^4 = 81` so `m=3`.

If by full you mean that each internal (i.e. non leaf) node has `m` children, then the example *is* full. With this definition, here is an example of a full 3-ary tree of depth 4 with 9 leaves:

```
        o
       /|\
      o o o
     /|\
    o o o
   /|\
  o o o
 /|\
o o o
```

I hope the question is clearer now. Is it homework? For now I'll leave it to you to compute the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

m.i+1 =n then in order to increase m we should increase i which is the number of internals.
m-1+m-1+m-1+m=81.Then m=21.